# Python - read great number of pictures in loop

Tags: python, image

I have a great number of pictures to use for calculation on python.
These pictures are named as MINtruc1000, MINtruc1250...
and it is in couple with picture MAXtruc1000, MAXtruc1250...

My aim is to call a couple of picture as MINtruc1000, MAXtruc1000 for each step of a loop...and i need to automaye it because of the great number of data

```
img0=skimage.data.imread('./test/MINtruc1000.tiff')
```

Comment: and i call it as the numbers increase

Comment: Use `glob.glob()` and define your file pattern.

Comment: i dont see sorry...could you give an example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly I imagine you could just do something like

```
def read_images(start, end):
    for i in range(start, end):
        img = skimage.data.imread("./test/MINtruc%s.tiff" % i)
        ...
```

if the images aren't in a consistently incrementing order, use glob

```
import glob
for im in glob.glob("./test/MINtruc*.tiff")
    img = skimage.data.imread(im)
    ...
```

If the problem is that this may use too much memory, look into creating a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) instead